# How can I update the old version of the class object to the new version?

Tags: python, class, object

With python 3.9.12, I have created MyClass objects and dumped it with pickle.
Then I've written few more line in def MyClass: to make more methods
To test it. I've loaded 10k MyClass object with pickle.

But newly coded methods are not working with loaded class object.
How can I update these class objects to newer version of class?

Comment: Quote from [Pickling Class Instances](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances): *" By default, pickle will retrieve the class and the attributes of an instance via introspection. When a class instance is unpickled, its `__init__()` method is usually **not** invoked. The default behaviour first creates an uninitialized instance and then restores the saved attributes."*

Comment: It was the matter of  an order. Thanks.